# Linux command to layout tab separated list nicely

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk

I would like to generate a log file with tab separated columns. It should have the following format with tab separated output for all but the comment field

```
time        date        alias   comment
10:09:20    03/06/13    jre     This is a test comment
```

I am using csh for historical purposes

```
set time = `perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%T", localtime)'`
set date = `perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%d/%m/%y", localtime)'`
set alias = jre
set comment = "This is a test comment"
```

Piping my text to  `column -t`

```
echo "time\tdate\talias\tcomment" | column -t > somefile
echo "$time\t$date\t$alias\t$comment" | column -t >> tt
```

I get almost what I want. However, the spaces in my comment field are also changed to tabs. Is there a way I can tab separate the first 3 fields but maintain space separation in the comments field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your comment is in the last column, try using `paste`. For example:

```
paste <(echo -e "this\tis\ttab\tseparated") <(echo "this is your comment")
```

By default, `paste` also joins on a tab character.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am getting an error message `Missing name for redirect` in csh but not in bash. I think this relates to extraneous whitespace characters. Csh is very frustrating

Comment: `bash -c paste <(echo -e "this\tis\ttab\tseparated") <(echo "this is your comment")` does the trick

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to do all the job with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = "\t"
        header = "time date alias comment"
        gsub( /\s+/, OFS, header )
        print header

        out[0] = strftime( "%T", systime() )
        out[1] = strftime( "%d/%m/%y", systime() )
        out[2] = "jre"
        out[3] = "This is a test comment"

        l = length( out )
        for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", out[ i ], i == l ? "" : OFS;
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
'
```

It yields:

```
time    date    alias   comment
11:45:00    03/06/13    jre This is a test comment
```

It is not printed just under the header, but for that case it should be better to use a formatted print (`printf`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
printf 'Time\tDate\tAlias\tComment\n' > file
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' $(date '+%T') $(date '+%d/%m/%y') jre "This is a comment" >> file
```